# SQL operand/no value specified errors, think it is syntax but unsure, could be something else?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm working on a project that uses servlets, mysql database and tomcat. One of the features needed is a user login page. My user LoginPage servlet (Nea.Servlets.LoginPage) takes email and password input in a form, and passes it to a Login servlet (Nea.Servlets.Login).

The Login servlet uses a function in another class SQLConnection (Nea.SQLConnection) to query the database and check if there exists a user who has that email and password (this is also the class where all of my SQL related functions are contained in).

The main part of Login servlet:

```
        SQLConnection sqlconnection = new SQLConnection();
        String Email = (String)request.getParameter("Email");
        String Password = (String)request.getParameter("Password");
if(sqlconnection.checkValidLogin(Email, Password) == false)//If the login details are incorrect:
        {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;URL='>");//redirects after 3 seconds
            out.println("<p style='color:red;'>Login unsuccessful! Please check your details and try again.</p>");      
            response.sendRedirect("/NEA/");
        }
        else//If the login details are correct:
        {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;URL=studenthome'>");//redirects after 3 seconds
            out.println("<p style='color:green;'>Login successful!</p>");
            response.sendRedirect("/NEA/studenthome");
        }
```

The main querying section of SQLConnection.checkValidLogin():

```
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, this.password);
            System.out.println("Database connected!");      
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT `Email`, `Password` FROM `users` WHERE `Email`=? AND `Password`=?;");//As the emails and passwords stored in the database are hashed, search for the hashed version of the input.

            System.out.println(ps);

            ps.setString(1, email);
            ps.setString(2, hashedPassword);

            System.out.println(ps);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            returnedEmail=rs.getString(1);
            returnedPassword=rs.getString(2);
```

As for the SQL Query in checkValidLogin(),

When I use:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT `Email`, `Password` FROM `users` WHERE `Email`=? AND `Password`=?;");
```

I  get the error: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2

On the other hand, when I use:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT `Email`, `Password` FROM `users` WHERE (`Email`=?, `Password`=?);");
```

I end up getting the error:  java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT: Using the first PreparedStatement (one that uses 'AND), I have put some dummy values in, and I can confirm that hashedPassword is NOT NULL, so the problem is not with the hashing algorithm.

Annoyingly, I've instead got a new error: Nea.SQLConnection.checkValidLogin(): java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set.
I cannot really understand why I am getting the result set error as I have written:

```
returnedEmail=rs.getString(1);
returnedEmail=rs.getString(2);
```

If you are interested, this is the Tomcat output I'm getting from outputting the email, hashedPassword and ps before and after setting  its parameters:

```
email=leg
hashedPassword=c7c8fc91abb8ed76c29a883381b92612dcd8235d6e7ddca8d81f6e87d5fab417
Database connected!
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@60719c1c: SELECT `Email`, `Password` FROM `users` WHERE `Email`=** NOT SPECIFIED ** AND `Password`=** NOT SPECIFIED **;
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@60719c1c: SELECT `Email`, `Password` FROM `users` WHERE `Email`='leg' AND `Password`='c7c8fc91abb8ed76c29a883381b92612dcd8235d6e7ddca8d81f6e87d5fab417';
```

Comment: Can you try it using this SQL string: `SELECT Email, Password FROM users WHERE Email=? AND Password=?;"` Notice that I removed the single quotes around several of the items

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Shouldn't be a problem for MySQL.

Comment: @BankBuilder Those are backticks (standard for MySQL), not quotes.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Just saying it's not the problem here.

Comment: I don't know how MySQL/JDBC works. Is there a chance it'll say "No value specified for parameter 2" if `hashedPassword` is null?

Comment: @thatotherguy just added some of the output in my edit! hashedPassword is not null so the problem is not with the hashing algorithm.

Comment: @BankBuilder What shmosel said... I'm not sure whether the backticks are absolutely required, but I've been told its good practice to use them.

Comment: The new error is simple enough: you have to call `rs.next()` before each row in the result set. If it returns `true`, you have a row to read. If it returns `false` then there were no matching users and you should fail the login.

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks! That fixed it